# Getting only first character in Output parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, output

I have defined output parameter as shown below:

C#:

```
scom.Parameters.Add("@User_ID",SqlDbType.VarChar,8).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output ;
```

Sql:

```
@User_ID varchar(8) output
```

I am getting complete string when executing procedure in Sql Server, but getting only first character in C#. I searched a lot and ensured that size is defined in both C# and Sql. Even I tried with fixed length character (Char(8)), but still getting only first character in C#. Please let me know what is the issue.

**C# Code:**

```
public bool CheckPhone(string phoneNumber)
{
    SqlConnection myconn=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        myconn.Open();
        SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand("AuthenticatePhone", myconn);
        scom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        scom.Parameters.Add("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(phoneNumber);
        scom.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Char, 8).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        scom.Parameters.Add("@User_Name", SqlDbType.Char, 120).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        scom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (scom.Parameters["@User_Name"] == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            UserID = (string)scom.Parameters["@User_ID"].Value;//.ToString();
            UserName = (string)scom.Parameters["@User_Name"].Value;//.ToString();
            myconn.Close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { 
        string error = e.InnerException + e.Message; 
    }
    finally 
    { 
        myconn.Close();
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Sql:**

```
Create procedure dbo.AuthenticatePhone

  @phoneNumber numeric(11,0)        ,
  @User_ID     varchar(8)    output ,
  @User_Name   varchar(120)  output
as
begin

  Select @User_ID   = convert(varchar(8),[User_ID]) ,
         @User_Name = [User_Name]
  from dbo.NRE_Users
  where PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber
  ;

  print @User_ID
  print @User_Name

end
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `SqlDbType.VarChar` ? `Char` doesn't match your procedure definition.

Comment: Yes I checked with VarChar but its not working.

Comment: Does @User_Name return all its characters?

Comment: No it didn't return. I am not sure what could be the issue. Now I am not using stored procedure. I am executing sql query through sql adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't repro for me. Given this stored procedure:

```sql
create procedure dbo.AuthenticatePhone

  @phoneNumber numeric(11,0)        ,
  @User_ID     varchar(8)    output ,
  @User_Name   varchar(120)  output

as

  set @User_ID   = '1234567890' -- should be truncated to '12345678'
  set @User_Name = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

  return 0
go
```

Running this SQL in SSMS:

```sql
 declare @userId   varchar(1000) = 'xxx'
 declare @userName varchar(1000) = 'yyy'
 exec AuthenticatePhone 1 , @User_ID = @userId out , @User_Name = @userName out
 select @userId,@userName
```

results in the expected results:

- `@userId` contains the expected `12345678`
- `@userName` contains the expected `The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.`

Executing it via C#:

```cs
using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( "Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;" ) )
using ( SqlCommand    command    = connection.CreateCommand() )
{

  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  command.CommandText = "dbo.AuthenticatePhone" ;

  SqlParameter phoneNumber = new SqlParameter {
    ParameterName = "@phoneNumber"           ,
    IsNullable    = true                     ,
    Direction     = ParameterDirection.Input ,
    Value         = 2125551212L              ,
    } ;
  command.Parameters.Add( phoneNumber ) ;

  SqlParameter userId = new SqlParameter {
    ParameterName = "@User_ID"                ,
    IsNullable    = true                      ,
    Direction     = ParameterDirection.Output ,
    DbType        = DbType.String             ,
    Size          = 1000                      ,
    Value         = DBNull.Value              ,
    } ;
  command.Parameters.Add( userId ) ;

  SqlParameter userName = new SqlParameter {
    ParameterName = "@User_Name" ,
    IsNullable    = true ,
    Direction     = ParameterDirection.Output ,
    DbType        = DbType.String ,
    Size          = 1000 ,
    Value         = DBNull.Value ,
    } ;
  command.Parameters.Add( userName ) ;

  connection.Open() ;
  int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery() ;
  connection.Close() ;

  Console.WriteLine( "Rows Affected: {0}"     , rowsAffected             ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "User ID:       {{{0}}}" , userId.Value   as string ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "User Name:     {{{0}}}" , userName.Value as string ) ;

}
```

likewise results in the expected

```
Rows Affected: -1
User ID:       {12345678}
User Name:     {The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.}
```

Even substituting your parameter definitions:

```cs
command.Parameters.Add("@phoneNumber", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 2125551212L ;
command.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Char, 8).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add("@User_Name", SqlDbType.Char, 120).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

You get the expected results.

Though you might note that `SqlDbType.Char` is a SQL `char(X)`. It's equivalent of `convert(char(120),'John Doe') in T-SQL. The .Net string will wind up padded with spaces to the specified length.

You might consider changing the type specifier to `SqlDbType.VarChar`: it will match the parameter declaration in the stored procedure *and* you won't find yourself needing to trim trailing whitespace from the string to make it useful.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I will give it a try again. Sorry I posted code with Char (actually I was testing out with various options). Earlier it was VerChar and it was not working. I will try it again now and let you know.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I tried with VarChar but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the below code:

`Parameter[param number].Size = 200;`

Answer (score 0):

change `SqlDbType.Char` to `SqlDbType.VarChar`

here:

```
scom.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Char, 8).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

scom.Parameters.Add("@User_Name", SqlDbType.Char, 120).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know a char in .net is only one character long. So you will need to change the parameter type to varchar

```
scom.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Varchar, 8).Direction = ParameterDirect
```

Comment: Little typo : `SqlDbType.VarChar` and not `SqlDbType.Varchar`

Comment: `SqlDbType` is the **SQL** data type involved. Not the CLR data type.

Comment: Hi, Sorry it was actually VarChar (I wrongly wrote it as Char), but it was not working.